# Weird whitespace or gap between section tabs titles in Foundation 4

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I am using Foundation 4.0.8, and there is a whitespace or gap between section tabs titles. It only happens when I first load the page, and it goes away when the window is resized. I found that the issue is with incorrect calculation of size of the first title tab. It adds style="left: Npx" to the second title tab, and N is larger than the size of the first title tab.

Has anyone noticed this? How can I go about mitigating this issue?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: It would help if you could provide an online example.

Comment: I am developing in dev env, and it's only small part of much larger application. It's kind of hard to have an online example...